# How to improve query time when explain looks good?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have big table 'placement' with **12 558 392** records;

When I try to get data using this table I face the performance problem(load time arount **5 seconds**).
When I explain this query all looks good but query time too long.

My query example:

```
    SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE om.*
    FROM order_materials om
          INNER JOIN material m ON om.material_id = m.id AND om.deleted = FALSE
          INNER JOIN placement p ON m.id = p.material_id AND m.deleted = FALSE AND p.deleted = FALSE
          INNER JOIN block b ON p.block_id = b.id AND b.deleted = FALSE
          INNER JOIN orders o ON om.order_id = o.id AND o.deleted = FALSE
          INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.mediaPlan_id = p.mediaplan_id
    WHERE
           b.advTable_id = 139
           AND p.date >= '2018-03-01 00:00:00' AND p.date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY om.material_id;
```

Explain:

```
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                             | key                  | key_len | ref                       | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,FK597C48D47B04A3                                                                                                                                                                                                  | FK597C48D47B04A3     | 5       | const                     |  455 |    50.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | NULL       | ref    | FK6ADE12E521DC3251,FK6ADE12E59B1CA2F1,FK6ADE12E5AFA9B543,date_ind,placement_b,placement_material_id_mediaplan_id_index,placement_material_id,placement_material_id_mediaplan_id_order_id_block_id_index,block_id_date_ind | FK6ADE12E521DC3251   | 5       | openmarket.b.id           |  135 |     0.82 | Using where                                  |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | pr    | NULL       | ref    | FKED8DCCEF9B1CA2F1                                                                                                                                                                                                        | FKED8DCCEF9B1CA2F1   | 5       | openmarket.p.mediaplan_id |    1 |   100.00 | Using index                                  |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY              | 4       | openmarket.p.material_id  |    1 |    50.00 | Using where                                  |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | om    | NULL       | ref    | FK_order_materials_1,FK_order_materials_2                                                                                                                                                                                 | FK_order_materials_2 | 4       | openmarket.p.material_id  |    2 |    50.00 | Using where                                  |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | PRIMARY              | 4       | openmarket.om.order_id    |    1 |    50.00 | Using where                                  |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+---------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE **order_materials**:

```
    CREATE TABLE `order_materials` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `last_mod_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `placements_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `FK_order_materials_1` (`order_id`),
      KEY `FK_order_materials_2` (`material_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_order_materials_1` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_order_materials_2` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `material` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251369 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE **placement**;

```
    CREATE TABLE `placement` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `changeDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `date` datetime NOT NULL,
      `plannedPosition` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `realPosition` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `positionWithPolitics` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `material_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `mediaplan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `block_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `visible` bit(1) NOT NULL,
      `blockStartTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `pricedPrice` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `actualStartTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `playedPosition` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `played_material_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `deleted` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `last_mod_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `conflict_status_lid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'lookup category placement_conflict',
      `conflict_by_type_in_block` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      `conflict_by_type_near` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      `conflict_by_time_overflow` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      `conflict_by_position` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
      `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `order_status_lid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `play_type_lid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `FK6ADE12E521DC3251` (`block_id`),
      KEY `FK6ADE12E59B1CA2F1` (`mediaplan_id`),
      KEY `FK6ADE12E5AFA9B543` (`material_id`),
      KEY `blockstarttime` (`blockStartTime`),
      KEY `date_ind` (`date`),
      KEY `bst_rp_ind` (`blockStartTime`,`realPosition`),
      KEY `status_ind` (`status`),
      KEY `FK_played_material` (`played_material_id`),
      KEY `FK_placement_1` (`conflict_status_lid`),
      KEY `FK_placement_2` (`order_id`),
      KEY `FK_placement_3` (`order_status_lid`),
      KEY `FK_placement_4` (`play_type_lid`),
      KEY `placement_b` (`date`,`blockStartTime`,`block_id`,`plannedPosition`),
      KEY `placement_material_id_mediaplan_id_index` (`material_id`,`mediaplan_id`),
      KEY `placement_material_id` (`material_id`,`mediaplan_id`,`order_id`),
      KEY `placement_material_id_mediaplan_id_order_id_block_id_index` (`material_id`,`mediaplan_id`,`order_id`,`block_id`),
      KEY `block_id_date_ind` (`block_id`,`date`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK6ADE12E521DC3251` FOREIGN KEY (`block_id`) REFERENCES `block` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK6ADE12E59B1CA2F1` FOREIGN KEY (`mediaplan_id`) REFERENCES `mediaplan` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK6ADE12E5AFA9B543` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `material` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_placement_1` FOREIGN KEY (`conflict_status_lid`) REFERENCES `lookups` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_placement_2` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `orders` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_placement_3` FOREIGN KEY (`order_status_lid`) REFERENCES `lookups` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_placement_4` FOREIGN KEY (`play_type_lid`) REFERENCES `lookups` (`id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_played_material` FOREIGN KEY (`played_material_id`) REFERENCES `played_material` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12578822 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Розміщення рекламного матеріалу')
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251369 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

After rewrite query with **exist** i have next explain

```
    +----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
    | id | select_type        | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                     | key                   | key_len | ref                       | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
    +----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
    |  1 | PRIMARY            | om    | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                              | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                      | 243300 |    50.00 | Using where |
    |  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | o     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY               | 4       | openmarket.om.order_id    |      1 |    50.00 | Using where |
    |  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                           | PRIMARY               | 4       | openmarket.om.material_id |      1 |   100.00 | Using where |
    |  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p     | NULL       | ref    | FK6ADE12E5AFA9B543,date_ind,placement_b,placement_material_id_mediaplan_id_index,placement_material_id,placement_material_id_mediaplan_id_order_id_block_id_index | placement_material_id | 5       | openmarket.m.id           |    101 |     0.82 | Using where |
    |  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pr    | NULL       | ref    | FKED8DCCEF9B1CA2F1                                                                                                                                                | FKED8DCCEF9B1CA2F1    | 5       | openmarket.p.mediaplan_id |      1 |   100.00 | Using index |
    |  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,FK597C48D47B04A3                                                                                                                                          | PRIMARY               | 4       | openmarket.p.block_id     |      1 |     5.00 | Using where |
    +----+--------------------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Do you want LEFT JOIN? If so, move the WHERE clause conditions to the ON clauses. (As it is now you get regular INNER JOIN result.)

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a group by clause is unwarranted

Comment: @jarlh If an inner join isn't in fact what was wanted then the JOINs could be removed altogether

Comment: @Strawberry, true!

Comment: Why do you use `distinct` if you already have `group by`? Values already will be distinct (as they will have different `material_id`). Try removing it (it can possibly remove filesort from explain) and also replace left joins with inner (as you already made them inner ones by your where conditions)

Comment: I removed distinct and move '.delete' to 'ON' but it still work in the same way.

Comment: Using temporary; Using filesort is *not* a good explain. This means that mysql is not able to perform the query in memory, so it has to store parts  of the queries on disk. This is the cause of your slowness. My first question is, why grouping by material_id if you don't perform any aggregating function? second question: do you have indexes on the joining filelds? third: have you considered using EXISTS instead of inner join?

Comment: @senape 1. I use group by to avoid dublication of column 2.  I have indexes for join column 3.What you mean?

Comment: @VladimirBilovus, if you share your table creation queries i can be more helpful

Comment: @senape  I`d added create queries to description on question

Comment: I will write an answer, because i have not enough space in the comment box :)

Comment: How many rows in blocks do you have with `advTable_id = 139`? How many rows in `placements` with `p.date >= '2018-03-01 00:00:00' AND p.date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'`? How many rows after the join (without group by)? Also, check if the `INNER JOIN product pr ON pr.mediaPlan_id = p.mediaplan_id` does what you think it does/is required for the intended result; it looks a bit fishy (although I obviously do not know your datamodel and intended result, so it might be correct, but you should double-check).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your schema, you are looking for a distinct list of "order_materials" to be filtered according to the other listed tables.
In my experience, you can't filter/group/distinct results with joins without suffering the "using temporary - using filesort"

In your case, anyway, since it looks that you don't need the values from the other tables, I believe it would be possible to rewrite your query removing all the joins and just using the [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) clause.

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE om.*
FROM order_materials om 
where 
om.deleted = false
and 
exists (
    select 1 
    from material m
    where exists 
        (select 1 from placement p 
        where m.id = p.material_id 
        AND m.deleted = FALSE 
        AND p.deleted = FALSE
        and p.date >= '2018-03-01 00:00:00' AND p.date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'
        and exists (select 1 from block b
            where p.block_id = b.id 
            AND b.deleted = FALSE
            and b.advTable_id = 139
            )
        and exists (select 1 from product pr 
            where pr.mediaPlan_id = p.mediaplan_id)
        )
    and m.id=om.material_id
)
and exists (select 1 from orders o 
    where om.order_id = o.id 
    AND o.deleted = FALSE)
```

The explain plan of such a query is:

```
+------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type        | table       | type   | possible_keys                     | key          | key_len | ref                | rows | Extra       |
+------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | om          | ALL    | order_id,material_id              | NULL         | NULL    | NULL               |    1 | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | m           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY      | 4       | abc.om.material_id |    1 | Using where |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | o           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                           | PRIMARY      | 4       | abc.om.order_id    |    1 | Using where |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | p           | ALL    | material_id,block_id,mediaplan_id | NULL         | NULL    | NULL               |    1 | Using where |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <subquery5> | eq_ref | distinct_key                      | distinct_key | 4       | func               |    1 |             |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | b           | eq_ref | PRIMARY,advTable_id               | PRIMARY      | 4       | abc.p.block_id     |    1 | Using where |
|    5 | MATERIALIZED       | pr          | index  | mediaPlan_id                      | mediaPlan_id | 5       | NULL               |    1 | Using index |
+------+--------------------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+------+-------------+
```

As you can see, no temporary, no filesort. Therefore, since exists is a boolean operator, you won't receive duplicates as it happens when you join.

Finally, please, be extremely careful: I wrote this answer on the fly, you need to check that the nested exists are consistent with your expected results, this iis not the final solution but just a shared hint on what I've learned so far.

Comment: I had tried this solution but it is work very slow  `4m 52s 307ms`

Comment: Can you post your explain plan? When I tried my proposal I worked on a very simple schema

Comment: I had added explain to question description

Comment: My mistake: the query i proposed returns ALL the rows of the order_material table. clearly, you need only those with `b.advTable_id = 139` and `p.date >= '2018-03-01 00:00:00' AND p.date <= '2018-04-01 00:00:00'` As I told you, this was just a hint, you need to refine the query. In this case, some joins can be necessary.

Comment: another suggestion, given the rows of the om table, is to change the order of the "where", so that you have the om table as internal, and take the values from the others

Answer (score 0):

`order_materials` seems to be a many:many mapping table.  The schema is inefficient.  Get rid of `id` and make the other changes suggested in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

`block` needs `INDEX(advTable_id, deleted, id)`

`placement` needs `INDEX(material_id, deleted, date)`

There are several redundant indexes.  Follow this rule:  If you have `INDEX(a, b)`, you don't need `INDEX(a)`.

`key_len = 5` usually refers to `INT NULL` -- check to see if they should be `INT NOT NULL`.